# Why do I get back a Traceback(most recent call last) error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have recently been working on a classifier that works on determining malignancy of breast cancer tumors. However I keep getting a traceback error at the end of the code.

```
def main():
# TODO
     print ("Reading in training data...")
     trainingSet = []
     trainingFile = "cancerTrainingData.txt"

     trainingSet = makeTrainingSet(trainingFile)
     print ("Done reading training data.\n")

     print ("Training classifier...")   

     trainedClassifier = trainClassifier(trainingSet)
     print ("Done training classifier.\n")

     print ("Present Classifier Stats")

     dumpStats(trainedClassifier[0], trainedClassifier[1], trainedClassifier[2]) 

     print ("Reading in test data...")
     testFile = "cancerTestingData.txt"
     testSet = makeTestSet(testFile)
     print ("Done reading test data.\n")

     print ("Classifying records...")

     classifiedTestSet = classifyTestRecords(testSet, trainedClassifier[0])

     print ("Done classifying.\n")

     reportAccuracy(classifiedTestSet)

     print ("Check some Patients")

     checkSomePatients(classifiedTestSet, trainedClassifier[0])    

     print ("Program finished.\n")

main()
```

The code gives back the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-10-db4d57bf1cdf> in <module>()
356     print ("Program finished.\n")
357
--> 358 main()
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Would you kindly show the traceback?

Comment: @KidusAfeword. Can you display the actual error message?

Comment: The error says TypeError, check data types, i.e. function params and your input

Comment: What's the full trace? This looks abbreviated.